# How to let a VirtualBox environment replace your Windows?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, multi-boot, bootable-media, virtual-desktop

I have a virtual environment in VirtualBox which I use so much that I would like it to replace my Windows. Is it possible to make a bootable USB to install this environment on my PC, or is there perhaps another way to do this?

The virtual environment's system is Ubuntu (64-bit) but there have been a lot of changes made to it which I don't want to lose.

(I do have a `.vdi` and `.vbox` file of the environment if this helps.)

Comment: Consider taking a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system).

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure is an untested idea indicating one possible approach.
I suggest using the Clonezilla, but other similar products may be equally suitable.
The BIOS and disk format of the VM must be compatible with your physical BIOS
(UEFI or legacy).

- Power up the VM, uninstall VM additions and shutdown
- Boot Clonezilla from the VM and clone the entire disk including all
  partitions to a bootable HDD or USB that is large enough
- Try to boot that disk
- If the disk cannot boot, try to repair its boot using a repair disk
  such as [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) 
  (don't overwrite the Windows disk by mistake)
- Ensure all hardware is supported and all devices are functional
- You may later similarly clone this disk to replace the Windows disk.

Before starting I suggest creating a backup image of the Windows disk
using a product that has a bootable restore disk, just in case.